# Fixing rails migration ran on server instead of git repo using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, spree, rails-migrations

I upgraded Spree Commerce from version 3.0 to version 3.1 but forgot to check in the migration files on Git from my local development environment

I instead generated the migration files on the server instead; I ended up committing the migrations from my development environment to git but now I'm having all sorts of problems with deploying because it's trying to run the migration when the tables exists.

I guess I don't really need the migrations to run since it's on the server?

Running `rake db:migrate:status` on the server shows:

```
   up     20151015124064  Add meta title to page.spree static content
   up     20151015124065  Add render as partial for layout for spree pages.spree static content
   up     20151015124066  Add pages stores.spree static content
  down    20160707102753  Create spree store credits.spree
  down    20160707102754  Create spree store credit categories.spree
  down    20160707102755  Create spree store credit events.spree
  down    20160707102756  Create spree store credit types.spree
  down    20160707102757  Add missing indexes.spree
  down    20160707102758  Remove duplicated indexes from multi columns.spree
  down    20160707102759  Remove user index from spree state changes.spree
  down    20160707102760  Add position to spree payment methods.spree
  down    20160707102761  Add taxable adjustment total to line item.spree
  down    20160707102762  Migrate payment methods display.spree
  down    20160707102763  Spree payment method store credits.spree
  down    20160707102764  Rename has and belongs to associations to model names.spree
  down    20160707102765  Spree store credit types.spree
  down    20160707102766  Add discontinued to products and variants.spree
  down    20160707102767  Remove shipping method id from spree orders.spree
  down    20160707102768  Add id column to earlier habtm tables.spree
  down    20160707102769  Add indexes.spree
  down    20160707102770  Add missing indices on user.spree auth
  down    20160707102771  Remove show in footer from spree pages.spree static content
```

On my location machine it shows:

```
   up     20151015124064  Add meta title to page.spree static content
   up     20151015124065  Add render as partial for layout for spree pages.spree static content
   up     20151015124066  Add pages stores.spree static content
   up     20160707102753  Create spree store credits.spree
   up     20160707102754  Create spree store credit categories.spree
   up     20160707102755  Create spree store credit events.spree
   up     20160707102756  Create spree store credit types.spree
   up     20160707102757  Add missing indexes.spree
   up     20160707102758  Remove duplicated indexes from multi columns.spree
   up     20160707102759  Remove user index from spree state changes.spree
   up     20160707102760  Add position to spree payment methods.spree
   up     20160707102761  Add taxable adjustment total to line item.spree
   up     20160707102762  Migrate payment methods display.spree
   up     20160707102763  Spree payment method store credits.spree
   up     20160707102764  Rename has and belongs to associations to model names.spree
   up     20160707102765  Spree store credit types.spree
   up     20160707102766  Add discontinued to products and variants.spree
   up     20160707102767  Remove shipping method id from spree orders.spree
   up     20160707102768  Add id column to earlier habtm tables.spree
   up     20160707102769  Add indexes.spree
   up     20160707102770  Add missing indices on user.spree auth
   up     20160707102771  Remove show in footer from spree pages.spree static content
```

I presume the migration status on the server should be `up` not `down`.

Is there any tips how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any data to lose you can drop those tables from your sql console and re-run capistrano deployment or **you can manually `up` the migration file from the server by**

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20151015124064
```

where version is second column of the result of `rake db:migrate:status`

> Note: remember you have to drop those tables on both cases

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I do have data and unfortunately, we I try to migrate:up it fails because the table already exists. Dropping tables is fine but there are unreversible migrations.

Comment: Unreversible migration is a part of spree tables or other tables and if possible can you list unreversible migration files.

Comment: And since migration not successful you can add 2 methods **def up** and **def down** instead of **def change** on all the migration which is irreversible  so you can write different logic for migration and rollback. And we can keep data by taking a dump of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to lose data and do it all over again there is an another approach that you can try.

A migration is marked as `up` or `down` based on whether migration version exists as a record within the schema_migrations table.
So, one way you can fix your issue is to add a file `app/models/schema_migration.rb` containing the following:

```
class SchemaMigration < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :version
  attr_accessible :version

  # you can call the method below via console or even call
  # or execute the commands directly from the rails console
  def self.fix_migrations
     # basically a list of all migrations that you run on server but are not marked as up
    down_migrations = %w(20160707102753 20160707102754 ... 20160707102771)
    down_migrations.each do |m|
      # this will add an entry in the schema_migrations datatable
      # on server so rake db:migrate won't try to run these again
      SchemaMigration.create(version: m) 
    end        
  end

end
```

And then via rails console, you execute: `SchemaMigration.fix_migrations`.

In case you need to run a specific migration again or if you accidentally added a migration version that has never been executed before, you can always remove the entry from schema_migrations using `SchemaMigration.find_by_version('xxxx').delete`. This will allow `rake db:migrate` to try to run that migration again.